# Changing style of the system tray icon at run time

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon, notification-area

I've created a system tray application using c#. And it is running successfully. Now the problem is, a notification window that has to be popped up when a particular event occurs(Not with a new icon but for the same icon which present in the notification area). The notification should last for few seconds and the notification area icon's colour should be changed till the window disappears.

Please suggest solutions. Thanks for helping!!!

Comment: What have you tried? Changing the icon is not that difficult, and works basically how you would expect. (Note: It's called the *notification area*, not the "system tray".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the class NotifyIcon you can set the Icon property:

```
notifyIcon.Icon = <Some Icon> (ex. Properties.Resources.IconRed, if in your resources).
```